# Where can more information about feats be found?

Tags: product-identification, l5r

The [L5R wiki](http://l5r.wikia.com/wiki/Feat) mentions Feats, but I don't recall seeing mention of them. Does anyone know which edition they come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took a little bit of following the white rabbit to be completely certain, but I followed the chain to an answer.  One of the examples of a feat given is named "Untouchable", which when you follow the link cites this particular feat to page 24 of the book Way of the Ninja.  The listing there is for the feat *Untouchable*:

> **Untouchable**
>
> *You are adept at dodging missile weapons and other ranged attacks*
>
> **Prerequisites:** Ninja level 12+, Tumble (15 ranks)
>
> **Benefit:** So long as you are not helpless, you are always considered to have total concealment against ranged attacks. Opponents suffer a 50% miss chance when attempting to strike you with such attacks.

Feats, as described in that snippet you attached are compatible with the d20 rules for L5R themed characters. Thus you need to look at the d20 System, most likely in relation to D&D 3rd and 3.5 editions due to the Rokugan setting introduced in the book Oriental Adventures.  Reading the Player's Handbook for either of these editions, as well as OA, will provide more in depth information as to what a feat is and how to use it.

If you are playing the 2nd Edition of L5R, and not the d20 counterpart, most of the books associated with it still have usable material but you must be careful to separate the d20 from the Roll & Keep mechanics.

Comment: If I had the reputation, I'd give your answer an upvote. As is, I believe that it's normal to let questions sit for a few hours/days to allow any additional answers to come up before I select an answer. Thanks for putting the effort into hunting down the answer!